# Utilizar pgAdmin 4 con atajos de teclado

Tags: pgadmin

Cordial saludo.
A sido muy interesante y practico para mi, utilizar diferentes aplicaciones por medio de atajos de teclado, es por ello que al comenzar a trabajar con pgAdmin 4, comencé a buscar algunos atajos que me permitan ejecutar acciones de forma rápida pero aun no he podido encontrar los de mi interés.
Agradezco su ayuda con los atajos de teclado que me permitan realizar las siguientes acciones:

1. abrir un Query Tool
2. cerrar un Query Tool
3. moverme entre varias ventas Query Tool
4. moverme de Query Tool a Browser y viceversa
5. abrir las opciones de una tabla (las opciones que aparecen al dar clic derecho sobre la tabla)
6. moverme de la zona de trabajo Query a la zona Data output

Comment: [Documentación](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/keyboard_shortcuts.html)

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo, en la pagina que me diste pude encontrar el atajo 1 (Alt+shif+Q), pero el resto de atajos no. Probé cada uno de los listado pero no logre obtener el atajo 1

Comment: Si los desarrolladores de pgadmin sólo dicen eso, qué podemos decirte nosotros? ;)